# Insert data into Npgsql/Postgresql database with C# windows forms

Tags: c#, postgresql, windows-forms-designer, npgsql

I am completely new to programming and I am trying to create a small app as a school project. I want it to be able to register and login users. I have already figured out how to create login part, but I am stuck on registration. I have created Insert function inside pgAdmin and it works but I cant make it work with my windows forms app.

This is my code so far:

```
using Npgsql;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjektV0._0._2
{
    public partial class frmRegister : Form
    {
        public frmRegister()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private NpgsqlConnection conn;
        string connstring = String.Format("Server={0}; Port={1};" +
                "User Id = {2}; Password={3};Database={4};",
                "localhost", "5432", "postgres", "23112001", "demo2");
        private NpgsqlCommand cmd;
        private string sql = null;

        private void frmRegister_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
        }

        private void Register_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }


        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sql = @"select * from u_insert(:_username,:_password)";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_username", txtEmail.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_password", txtPswrd.Text);
                if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Registered successfuly", "Well done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                    txtEmail.Text = txtPswrd.Text = txtConPswrd.Text = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

pgAdmin part:

```
create function u_insert
(
    _username character varying,
    _password character varying
)returns int as
$$
begin
    insert into tbl_users
    (
        username,
        password
    )values
    (
        _username,
        _password
    );
    if found then
        return 1;-----success-----
    else
        return 0;-----fail-----
    end if;
end
$$
language plpgsql
```

As I said my login part work even through my program and all other functions (insert,update) work only inside pgAdmin.

Comment: I'm wondering as to `if found then` where did it come from? Does the function even work?

Comment: what happens when you run this code (the c# code)

Comment: When i try to test the function (`select * from u_insert('x','y')`) inside pgAdmin it does work.

Comment: and the c# code - what happens?

Comment: I can run the app and insert the values but clicking the button does nothing.

Comment: It doesnt even show the error I want it to show

Comment: define 'does nothing' your code has MEssageBox after both success and failure, it must do something

Comment: Are you married to the idea of a function?  This seems grossly overkill for the task at hand, inserting a record.  Also, for what it's worth, I try to avoid DB code in the UI.  Some separation really helps with project organization.

Comment: There are couple of issues: primarily you need `select 1` not `select *`. Do not cache the connection or command objects, create them when you need them, always dispose with `using`.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify my comment...  why the function/procedure?  It seems dramatic overkill for an insert.  I would put something like this outside of my form (in a CRUD class somewhere):

```
public static int UpdateUser(string UserId, string Password, out string ErrorMessage)
{
    int result = 0;
    ErrorMessage = null;

    NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    sb.Host = "localhost";
    sb.Port = 5432;
    sb.Username = "postgres";
    sb.Password = "23112001";
    sb.Database = "demo2";

    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(sb.ToString()))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string dml = "insert into tbl_users (username, password) values (:USER, :PW)";

        using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(dml, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("USER", UserId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PW", Password);

            try
            {
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And then within the Button Click event you can simplify it to this:

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string error;
    int insertedRows = CrudClass.UpdateUser(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text, out error);

    if (insertedRows == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Registered successfuly", "Well done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        txtEmail.Text = txtPswrd.Text = txtConPswrd.Text = null;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [connection string](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html) is invalid for Postgres. It should rather be `"Host={0}; Port={1}; Username= {2}; Password={3};Database={4};"`

Then the [parameter placeholder](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html) should be `@`, not `:`

Tip 1: read the doc of the proper database

Note that the connection string is invalid, and opening the connection likely throws an error. In the `catch` section, you start by closing the connection then you display the error message. If closing the connection fails and throws an error, the code after it will never be executed.

Tip 2: don't do anything that can throw an error within a `catch` section. You can nest another `try..catch` though.

Comment: Npgsql is pretty forgiving and will accept either @ or :.  We use : because of portability with Oracle, which is the other primary DBMS here.

Comment: Thank you. This actually helped. Now I at least get an error